# Unspecified error when trying to connect to an MS Access database on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I've both Visual Studio 2010 (Premium) and MS Access 2010 installed. I'm just trying to connect to a .mdb database file from the server explorer and it doesn't work. I get the following message: "Unspecified error". If I try to add a database on the App_Data folder and open it, I get the same error. I've tried with .accdb and .mdb files but both give the same problem.

I have also Visual Studio 2005 installed on the same machine. And it works without any problems.

Anyone has any thoughts about it?

Thank you

Comment: Migrate your Access database to SQL 2008 R2 Express if feasible. It would probably save lots of time and heartache into the future.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for you answer! Unfortunatelly it's not possible. I would like to mainly to take advantage of the EF 4. But this project has as a technical requirement that requires the use of the Jet database.

Comment: Code? It might be that you've got an inappropriate connect string. If it's an MDB, it shouldn't matter that A2010 is installed, as you can use Jet 4 (a part of the OS) and not worry about the ACE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate references in you VS2010 project for Access databases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this counts as an answer but, the issue is with Visual Studio 2010.  I too need to connect to an Access database (tactical solution, migration not possible) and in VS2010 I get the "unspecified error".  It fails if I try an ODBC based connection too.  I can connect fine using SSIS, and as it turns out, in VS2008.

My current solution is to create my class library in VS2008 and reference the compiled DLL in my VS2010 project.  I haven't got the time to try and fix my VS2010 install at the moment.  When I do, I'll upgrade my 2008 project.

An aside: I think most people on here would migrate to a better database if they could, and are only connecting to Access databases because they have no choice.